# RD Session Host 2012R2 Session settings set via GP are not reflected in QuickSessionCollection Properties

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I have a Quick Start RDS deployment on one host under Windows 2012R2, domain member. I applied group policies on this host that limited sessions timeouts:

Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Session Time Limits:

End session when time limits are reached Enabled

Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions Enabled

Idle session limit: 1 hour

Set time limit for disconnected sessions Enabled

End a disconnected session 1 hour

Gpresult shows these settings are applied successfully, and the server drops the sessions according to the settings.

When I go to 
 Server Manager\Remote Desktop Services\Collections\QuickSessionCollection proprties I can see [image: QuickSessionCollection Proprties]

Time outs are set to never.
 **Why I don't see the actual settings here?** Is there something similar to RDP-TCP properties in 2008 R2 server?
[image: RDP-Tcp properties]
Where I can see the settings set by GPO.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the Session settings with the Session Collection settings dialog (your first screenshot) and the session hosts will reconfigure to match your selection.

You shouldn't tweak the settings with a GPO.

I highly recommend you to disable/remove the GPO that you created, and reconfigure the settings that you want within the Session Collection properties in Server Manager. When you'll hit the "Apply" button, Server Manager will configure remotely your session hosts (hence the delay when you click "Apply")